# Datos duplicados en Array [JS]

Tags: javascript

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en Javascript, recién estoy viendo temas como Array & Objetos...haciendo una práctica se me presenta el siguiente problema: al agregar datos en el array, se me "pisan" los datos anteriores con el último que ingresé: por ejemplo si la primera vez se ingresa "Raúl" "05/12/21" y luego "Pedro" "15/12/21" al hacer un console.table del array me figura dos veces "Pedro" "15/12/21".

¿Alguien podrá indicarme que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? Agradecería si pueden darme una mano a entenderlo mejor!

Gracias de antemano!

Pd: el ejercicio es muy básico y carece de varias cosas, es sólo a efectos de entender el tema de arrays que estoy estudiando.

```
class Reserva {
    constructor(nombre, fecha) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        

        this.tomaReserva = function(n, f){
            this.nombre = n;
            this.fecha = f;

            while(this.nombre == "" || this.fecha == ""){
                
                if(this.nombre == ""){
                    alert("Debe completar el campo Nombre y Apellido");
                    this.nombre = prompt("Nombre y Apellido:");
                } else if(this.fecha == ""){
                    alert("Debe indicar una fecha");
                    this.fecha = prompt("Reserva mesa para (dd/mm/aa):");
                }
            }

            console.log(`Reserva Exitosa!)
        }

    }
}

let opcion = ""
let reservar = new Reserva();
let reservas = [];

function tomarReserva(){

    do{
    
    var nombre = prompt("Nombre y Apellido:");
    var fecha = prompt("Reserva mesa para (dd/mm/aa):");

    
    reservar.tomaReserva(nombre, fecha);
    reservas.push(reservar);

    opcion = prompt("Querés hacer otra reserva? (S/N)");

    if(opcion.toLowerCase() == "n" ){
        alert("Gracias por reservar con nosotros!");
    }

    } while(opcion.toLowerCase() != "n" )
}


tomarReserva();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las variables de objetos no deben tener nombres de acciones, sino nombres relacionados a la clase que representan

```
let objReserva = null;
```

dentro del do  while colocar , los métodos se describen como acciones, cambiar tomaReserva por , tomarReserva.

```
objReserva = new Reserva();
objReserva.tomarReserva(nombre, fecha);
```

Se genera una nueva instancia en cada iteración porque literalmente estamos construyendo un nuevo objeto con atributos diferentes.

Comment: Muchas gracias David! Haré los cambios que comentas. Agradezco tu ayuda!